# Is a reload of a <div> seen as a reload of a page? PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, session

Basically I have a setup like this :

```
<body> 
<div id="header">
   <h3> Header </h3>
</div>

<div id="body">
</div>

<div id="foot">
</div>
```

The idea here is to guide the user through a six step wizard of filling in data to calculate a value.

Each step is getting loaded into the `<div id="body">` the first step gets load in through jQuery, and the steps after that get loaded in through a JavaScript function.

The steps are called : step01.php, step02.php etc...

now my question is :  when I load from step01.php to step02.php in the `<div id="body">`
is that seen as a page reload? Because I want to save the variables which are filled in in step01.php into a session, or into a other .php file. But since php is serverside I wanted to know if a file reload in the div is seen as a full page reload?

If this is not possible without a full page reload, please suggest anything else...
I've read some documentation about AJAX but it still seems very vague to me. So if anyone has a "newbie-tutorial" please suggest.

At this moment I'm saving the variables in a JavaScript file, the make cookies out of it, and then extract the variables out of the cookies using php. But I know there is an easier way.

Comment: Use jquery load function which is pretty simple. Read their documentation. You can refresh only particular DIV instead of whole page

Comment: I could not find the specific question, but yes, what u need is ajax. And with ajax, you do not reload the page (URL does not change unless you force it). With ajax, you make a call to server and get a response. If you return an html, you can push it to your `<div id="body">`.

Comment: "seen as a full page reload" - by who, PHP or the user?

Comment: This might be of use : http://thecodemine.org/ It's an ajax wizard based on jquery with lots of examples to learn from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is considered a "page load" to your server side php scripts.  Anything you put in the session will be there for the next reload of the div.

Answer (score 2):

> But since php is serverside I wanted to know if a file reload in the div is seen as a full page reload?

In this conext the answer is: yes.
Server-side PHP has no idea about that div element you're using on the client. In general php puts very little interest in what the client is doing with data/ouput of the server-side scripts.
All it cares about is the http roundtrip that is taking place both when you do a complete page reload or when you use ajax.
For the php core it's all the same. Request comes in, some initialization takes place, scripts are processed, output is sent to the client (as a stream of bytes - at this level php has no "understanding" of what you're sending to the client; html, plain-text, images, application code, all the same to php), some garbage collection takes place, shut down mechanisms kick in, done.

Answer (score 0):

They are not page reloads if you're just loading into a div using jQuery. i.e. the url in the address bar remains the same.